# Service worker does not cache assets in offline mode in chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to test my pwa app in offline mode in chrome, but for some reason service worker doesn't cache the assets. When I click offline in devtools and restart the app, I'm getting 504 (Gateway Timeout) errors. But when I turn off internet physically it works as it should. See the video below.

https://www.loom.com/share/4ac8ed9316394781b943a1c6dc6cddb7

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "SmartPass",
  "short_name": "SmartPass",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "./icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "./icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "./icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "./icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "./icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "./icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "./icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "./icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

and ngsw.config

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I expect that this code works in offline mode in chrome, but it doesn't, and I'm trying to find the reason of this behavior.

Comment: Have you tested your app with the Lighthouse tool to make sure there are no errors to be fixed?  also the "start_url": "/" is at the root, but your video shows the app is in a subfolder "/app"

Comment: @Mathias I tried to set the start_url to /app but I'm getting the same errors. Also I tested the app in  Lighthouse and, everything is ok except "Does not redirect http trafic to https", all other tests are ok.

Comment: You then may need to add code to your .htaccess file to redirect all http requests to https

Comment: If you are just testing in your localhost, you may want to test at the root and not /app. Looks like your app is running @ /app but going after things in /assets when they are probably located in /app/assets. Make local testing easier for yourself.

Comment: @Mathias So how the manifest.json should look like, to test it properly ? Do  I have to switch start url to "/app/assets" ? Or just "/" ?

Comment: @Mathias Also, my, assets folder placed in src folder, not in the app folder. Check the screenshot below 

https://snag.gy/0mnWdg.jpg

Comment: @Mathias I've just realized, this files are loading by http request, not by https. Is there a probability that this is the reason of these errors ?

Comment: HTTPS is required for a valid PWA (where the code is located). I THINK you could have some of your content HTTP, but that would cause many browser warnings for your users. So it's not something anyone would really do.

Comment: The start_url should be the path to where your app is located. Most of the time that is "start_url": "/"

Comment: After you run "ng serve" or "ng build" the compiled files you run to view your site are not the same as the source files you work on and see in your development IDE.